# pygame how to check mouse coordinates

Tags: python, position, pygame, mouse

I am making a multiple choice quiz game with python and pygame. I have circles and what a want is when you click on the circle it will change the width and make the circle full. But I don't know of a python function that can do that

Heres my code so far:

```
    # Controls the width of the circles
    width_1 = 2
    width_2 = 2
    width_3 = 2
    width_4 = 2

    # Circles
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 230], 7, width_1)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 260], 7, width_2)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 290], 7, width_3)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 320], 7, width_4)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
```

I want to have something so that if the mouse is hovering over the circles AND mousebuttondown AND event.button == 1 then change the width to 0 (Fill it in)

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is not all my code

Answer (score 10):

you can just do
`x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` then
`print(x, y)`

Lets say we wanted to make some Flying blocks from one position to another.
We could do something like this

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys, random, math, fractions

pygame.init()
Screen_Width = 800
Screen_Height = 600

Total_Display = pygame.display.set_mode((Screen_Width, Screen_Height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Blocks(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        all_sprite_list.add(self)
        block_list.add(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,32))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.change_y = 0
        self.change_x = 0

    def blockMove (self, cursor_pos_x, cursor_pos_y, player_pos_x, player_pos_y):

        block_vec_x = cursor_pos_x - player_pos_x
        block_vec_y = cursor_pos_y - player_pos_y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(block_vec_x ** 2 + block_vec_y ** 2)
        block_vec_y = (block_vec_y / vec_length) * 5
        block_vec_x = (block_vec_x / vec_length) * 5
        self.change_y += block_vec_y
        self.change_x += block_vec_x

    def update(self):

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
```

Now well make a simple player class just for a position to fire the blocks to the mouse position well place this right in the middle of the window!

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        player_list.add(self)
        self.rect = Rect(400,300,16,16)
        self.image = pygame.surface((16,16))

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

block = Blocks(16,16)
player = Player()

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    for e in pygame.event.get()
        if e == pygame.Quit:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
```

Here is where we get the mouse position we set Mouse_X and Mouse_Y = mouse.get_pos() which will output (x, y) or Mouse_X = mouse pos x and Mouse_Y = mouse pos y. You can also out put the position of the mouse by adding a print(Mouse_x & "  " & Mouse_y)

```
    Mouse_x, Mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        block = Blocks(16,16)
        block.blockMove(Mouse_x, Mouse_y, player.rect.x, player.rect.y)
        block.rect.x = player.rect.x
        block.rect.y = player.rect.y
    block.update()
    Total_Display.fill((255,0,0))
    for sprite in all_sprite_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(Total_Display,(0,0,0), sprite)
    for blocks in block_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(Total_Display, (0,0,0), block)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

### I probably went a little overboard but hey hope this helps someone out there!
And here's the entire thing just to make sure I didn't make a mistake

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys, random, math, fractions

pygame.init()
Screen_Width = 800
Screen_Height = 600

Total_Display = pygame.display.set_mode((Screen_Width, Screen_Height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Blocks(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        all_sprite_list.add(self)
        block_list.add(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,32))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.change_y = 0
        self.change_x = 0

    def blockMove (self, cursor_pos_x, cursor_pos_y, player_pos_x, player_pos_y):

        block_vec_x = cursor_pos_x - player_pos_x
        block_vec_y = cursor_pos_y - player_pos_y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(block_vec_x ** 2 + block_vec_y ** 2)
        block_vec_y = (block_vec_y / vec_length) * 5
        block_vec_x = (block_vec_x / vec_length) * 5
        self.change_y += block_vec_y
        self.change_x += block_vec_x

    def update(self):

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        player_list.add(self)
        all_sprite_list.add(self)
        self.rect = Rect(400,300,16,16)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((16,16))


all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

block = Blocks(16,16)
player = Player()

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)


    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

    Mouse_x, Mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        block = Blocks(16,16)
        block.update()
        block.blockMove(Mouse_x, Mouse_y, player.rect.x, player.rect.y)
        block.rect.x = player.rect.x
        block.rect.y = player.rect.y
    block.update()
    Total_Display.fill((255,0,0))
    for sprite in all_sprite_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(Total_Display,(0,0,0), sprite)
    for blocks in block_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(Total_Display, (0,0,0), block)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` ([docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html))

> `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` get the mouse cursor position get_pos() -> (x,
>   y) 
>   Returns the X and Y position of the mouse cursor. The position is
>   relative the the top-left corner of the display. The cursor position
>   can be located outside of the display window, but is always
>   constrained to the screen.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would I check the specific x and y position.

Comment: How would I check for the position in an if statement?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, you would need the mouse coordinates. You could do that like this:

```
mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Then you would need a function that would check if the mouse is inside of the circles. To do this you would need a hitbox for the circles. A circular hitbox is hard to make so you could use a square one by doing the following:

```
def check_pressed ():
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if click != (0, 0, 0):
        if mousex >= buttonx and mousex <= buttonx + button_width and 
        mousey >= buttony and mousey <= buttony + button_height:
            #run function to make button bigger and run a clicked event
```

Add this check_pressed function to your main loop.
Hope this helps!